# Populate temp variable within stored procedure using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I am declaring an int variable that needs to be populated using a dynamic sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_aTABLE_ADD
/*

    stored procedure variables

*/
AS

     DECLARE @count int
     SET @count = 1
     DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max)

/*
     SET UP @qry which will look like this
     SELECT @count = count(*) FROM aTABLE WHERE (col1 = 'val1' AND col2 = 'val2'...)
*/


/*
     How to get the value of @count so that I can continue with add process
*/

IF @count = 0
BEGIN
   /*add logic*/
END
```

Comment: Looks like you're already selecting the value of count(*) into `@count`, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Use `sp_executeSQL` and an output parameter:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 1
DECLARE @qry   NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @qry = N'set @count = (....)'

EXEC sp_executesql @qry, N'@count INT OUTPUT', @count OUTPUT
    
SELECT @count
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try and work with a temporary table like this

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(cnt INT)
DECLARE @qry nvarchar(max)

-- Insert the count returned by dynamic SQL into temp table
SET @qry = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE condition'
INSERT INTO @tmp EXEC(@qry)

DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = (SELECT TOP 1 cnd FROM @tmp)
```